# Android Camera Touch Focus

Tags: android, camera, focus

I am trying to make a custom camera application I want to let the users can choose the focus mode in this application.

The focus mode is auto focus on default .

if I want to set the cameraView to be clickable such that when I touch one point onto the screen, the focus of the camera is on that point?   how can be start with?
 the below is my code

```
public void takePhoto(File photoFile, String workerName, int width, int height,   int        quality) {
if (getAutoFocusStatus()){
    camera.autoFocus(new AutoFocusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onAutoFocus(boolean success, Camera camera) {
            camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
        }
    }); 
}else{
    camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
}

this.photoFile = photoFile;
this.workerName = workerName;
this.imageOutputWidth = width;
this.imageOutputHeight = height;
}

public void takePhoto(File photoFile, int width, int height, int quality) {
takePhoto(photoFile, null, width, height, quality);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you touch a point on the screen, you should get a [Camera.Area](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Area.html). Focus area only has effect if the current focus mode is FOCUS_MODE_AUTO, FOCUS_MODE_MACRO, FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO, or FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_PICTURE. Then you should call the method [setFocusAreas](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setFocusAreas%28java.util.List%3Candroid.hardware.Camera.Area%3E%29) to trgigger focus. The camera's field of view is mapped from top-left corner(-1000, -1000) to bottom-right corner(1000, 1000). So you have to make a coordinate conversion.